# Establish a controlled rotation on gears

Tags: mechanical-engineering, motors, gears

I am a 3d designer trying to build a simple device for my project and I have a problem. As you can see in schema below, point G has weight on it and it needs to be a controlled, vertical rotation. I am afraid that when I build this, it will go faster or slower on sides. Rotation needs to be stable and I need rotation to stop where it is, as soon as motor stops.

- Can a mini motor achieve this and what kind?
- Do I need to add extra parts to the device and what are they?

Thanks in advance and I am looking forward to answers.

[image: schema]

Comment: 3D  designer seems a bit ambigious to me. Is that a 3D artist or industrial designer?

Comment: Well, actually a software engineer but the project I am working on demanded so many 3d models and prints that I don't know what I am now :D

Comment: Do you mean by 'controlled, vertical rotation' that the part in your diagram is rotating in the vertical plane, and therefore the motor must raise/lower the mass G?

Comment: When you talk about 'go faster or slower on sides' are are you wanting to control the speed in a certain direction (e.g. vertical speed)? Most motors will rotate at a fixed speed when driven by a fixed voltage (and with a constant load), which will provide a sinusoidal speed if considered in only one axis. To change this you  would need to control things either electrically, or mechanically, or both.

Comment: @welf By controlled, I mean stable speed. Basically rotation like arms of a clock. It is on planning stage and because I have no knowledge of motors, I was scared that with the weight on the tip of arm, it would do an uncotrolled rotation because of gravity. As suggested by joojaa, stepper motors resists certain amount of force that is not produced by motor so you will have a stable rotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest, to implement would be to use a stepper motor with enough hold torque or possibly detent torque if you need the thing to hold even unenergized. The benefit of this is also that you do not need a closed loop controller as the stepper either moves a step or skips it. Which means as long as your stepper is strong enough its not a issue.

Now your post mentions gears. While i think involving gears is a bit premature as you havent done motor selection, remember that gears change the effective torque of your motor. So it also affects the effective hold  and detent torque.

Comment: Thanks I will definitely check stepper motors and get back with results.